# cakephp tmp/cache - access denied

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have CakePHP app.
I set "chamod -R 0666 tmp" to make all the folders/files in tmp folder writable.
Everything was fine.

Yesterday I used some console scripts ('cake i18n' shell). After this I lost all permissions to the tmp folder - I cant open it, cant change perissions, can't do anything - please help - how it is possible?

Comment: Try to login with Administrator login credentials and provide 777 recursive permission to app/tmp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using:
    sudo chmod -Rf 0777 tmp

Answer (score 0):

Use chmod -R 0777 tmp to make all folders under tmp and including tmp writable. Setting it to chamod 0666 makes tmp directory accessible for everyone, but doesn't make the files executable.